# Manipulate the "Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description" when processed locally?

Tags: swift, alert, speech-to-text

I am building a speech recognition app and therefore I need to activate the "Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description" in the plist.

Unfortunately the default text says: "Speech data from this app will be sent to Apple to process your request".

But my app uses the on device speech to text engine:

```
recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
```

What (hopefully) means no connection to apple servers is needed.
Is there a way to manipulate the default alert text or at least to set it the right way?

Comment: Use some other engine which is fully offline

Comment: The recognition is performed on a device, but communication with Apple is still required (for tracking purpose), therefore text is meaningful. This is a specifics of Apple engine.

Comment: @Krusel Did you find a way to stop this alert from being displayed?